# Angular Dropdown Multiselect

Tags: typescript, angular5, graphql, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to use the Angular 4 dropdown multiselect from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-dropdown-multiselect)

And I want to get the users from my database.

Typescript file:

```
this._httpWebService.Usermulti()
    .subscribe(res => {
        const userData = res;
        this.testar = userData.data.userList;
        this.myOptions=this.testar;
        console.log(this.testar);
    });
```

HTML file:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" [(ngModel)]="share" (change)="onChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

As a result I'm having an array of objects in the console log but I get empty options in the multiselect on the front.

I'm using for the backend GraphQL and angular 5 in frontend.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(this.testar)? Please provide the pattern at least if the real content is to be kept secret.

Comment: [
  {
    "Id": "RH001",
    "firstName": "Mario Abdi "
  },
  {
    "Id": "RH002",
    "firstName": "Karim Sbain "
  },
  {
    "Id": "RH003",
    "firstName": "Sarra Kari "
  },
  {
    "Id": "RH004",
    "firstName": "Mehdi Kn "
  }
]


and myOptions must be like this i think : 

this.myOptions = [
  { id:"1", name: 'Marouen Abdi' },
  { id: "2", name: 'Hatem Abdi' },];

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [{"Id": "RH001", "firstName": "Mario Abdi " }, 
> { "Id": "RH002", "firstName": "Karim Sbain " }, 
> { "Id": "RH003", "firstName": "Sarra Kari " }, 
> { "Id": "RH004", "firstName": "Mehdi Kn " } ]
> ```
>
> and myOptions must be like this i think :
>
> ```
>  this.myOptions = 
>  [{id:"1", name: 'Marouen Abdi' }, 
>  { id: "2", name: 'Hatem Abdi' },];
> ```

Well, it seems that your field **userData.data.userList** doesn't deliver an object but a plain JSON-string.

Please try to parse it before binding it to your page:

```
    this.testar = JSON.parse(userData.data.userList);
    this.myOptions=this.testar;
    console.log(this.testar);
```